# How to get facebook user id after login

Tags: users, social-network

I am using Drupal for facebook module to login into my drupal site. How can i get facebook user id after user login to my site. I want to store user details and give a chance to edit his profile. I can able to track firstname and Lastname,Email But i can not able to track user id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping information is stored in the fb_user table in the database.

I'm not aware of any API functions the module provides for querying this data but I wouldn't be surprised if something exists.

If all you are doing is authentication I'd have a look at [FBOauth module](http://drupal.org/project/fboauth) instead, it provides a similar table and makes the whole process a lot easier.